# Swift - How to debug a core data relationship error?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data

Im creating a core data object of a product that also has many other products associated with it in a many to many relationship.

When converting my json im checking if that product has associated products and then adding a relationship.

```
if let relatedItems = response["related"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    // create the related items
    for d in relatedItems {
        let related = try createAssociatedFromResponse(response: d)
        product.addToAssociatedProducts(related)
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    }
}
```

This is producing a inconstant error - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Objects should not be both modified and additional'

I have tried checking if the object already exists as a relationship but am still getting this error.

Edit - Full code that converts json into core data objects

```
func createFromResponse(response: Dictionary<String, Any>) throws -> Product {
        
        let productID = response["id"] as! NSNumber
        
        var product: Product!
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Product> = Product.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productID = %@", productID)
        
        if let fetchedProduct = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            product = fetchedProduct
        } else {
            product = (NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Product", into: self.managedObjectContext) as! Product)
            product.productID = productID
        }
        
        product.name = response["name"] as? String
        product.ref = response["ref"] as? String
        product.desc = response["description"] as? String
        product.imageURL = response["image"] as? String
        product.image = nil
        product.thumbImageURL = response["thumb"] as? String
        product.thumbImage = nil
        product.pdfURL = response["pdf"] as? String
        product.manufacturerUrl = response["manufacturer_url"] as? String
        
        if let categoriesInHierarchy = response["categories"] as? NSArray
        {
            if categoriesInHierarchy.count == 3
            {
                if let topCategory = categoriesInHierarchy[0] as? [String:Any] {
                    product.topCategoryID = topCategory["id"] as? NSNumber
                    product.topCategoryName = topCategory["name"] as? String
                }
                
                if let subCategory = categoriesInHierarchy[1] as? [String:Any] {
                    product.subCategoryID = subCategory["id"] as? NSNumber
                    product.subCategoryName = subCategory["name"] as? String
                }
                
                if let bottomCategory = categoriesInHierarchy[2] as? [String:Any] {
                    product.bottomCategoryID = bottomCategory["id"] as? NSNumber
                    product.bottomCategoryName = bottomCategory["name"] as? String
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        if let relatedItems = response["related"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            // create the related items
            for d in relatedItems {
                let related = try createAssociatedFromResponse(response: d)
                product.addToAssociatedProducts(related)
            }
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        }
        
        return product
    }

func createAssociatedFromResponse(response: Dictionary<String, Any>) throws -> Product {
        
        let productID = response["id"] as! NSNumber
        
        var product: Product!
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Product> = Product.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productID = %@", productID)
        
        if let fetchedProduct = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first {
            product = fetchedProduct
        } else {
            product = (NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Product", into: self.managedObjectContext) as! Product)
            product.productID = productID
        }
        
        product.name = response["name"] as? String
        product.ref = response["ref"] as? String
        product.desc = response["description"] as? String
        product.imageURL = response["image"] as? String
        product.image = nil
        product.thumbImageURL = response["thumb"] as? String
        product.thumbImage = nil
        product.pdfURL = response["pdf"] as? String
        product.manufacturerUrl = response["manufacturer_url"] as? String
        
        if let categoriesInHierarchy = response["categories"] as? NSArray
        {
            if categoriesInHierarchy.count == 3
            {
                if let topCategory = categoriesInHierarchy[0] as? [String:Any] {
                    product.topCategoryID = topCategory["id"] as? NSNumber
                    product.topCategoryName = topCategory["name"] as? String
                }
                
                if let subCategory = categoriesInHierarchy[1] as? [String:Any] {
                    product.subCategoryID = subCategory["id"] as? NSNumber
                    product.subCategoryName = subCategory["name"] as? String
                }
                
                if let bottomCategory = categoriesInHierarchy[2] as? [String:Any] {
                    product.bottomCategoryID = bottomCategory["id"] as? NSNumber
                    product.bottomCategoryName = bottomCategory["name"] as? String
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        product.associatedProducts = nil
        
        return product
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to add the Core Data debug flags to help with debugging. See eg [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the `try self.managedObjectContext.save()` after the for loop, like this:

```swift
if let relatedItems = response["related"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    // create the related items
    for d in relatedItems {
        let related = try createAssociatedFromResponse(response: d)
        product.addToAssociatedProducts(related)
    }
    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
}
```

Edit:
How are you creating objects in `createAssociatedFromResponse`?

Edit 2:
You should not use `NSManagedObjectContext` in different threads, wrap your functions in `perform` block, like this:

```swift
self.managedObjectContext.perform { 
 if let relatedItems = response["related"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    // create the related items
    for d in relatedItems {
        let related = try createAssociatedFromResponse(response: d)
        product.addToAssociatedProducts(related)
    }
    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
 }
}
```

Comment: Iv have tried that but i still have the same error. Ive added the full code now.

Comment: createFromResponse function is called on which thread ? I suppose its on background thread?

Comment: Yes it is called multiple times when looping through the JSON response

Comment: Okay, than you should wrap your core data functions in perform block. 

self.managedObjectContext.perform { }